# For loop behavior in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have these two function that calculate the numbers of animals based upon some input in another function. I want to know the behavior of this function. If i input 20 heads and 56 legs i get 8 pigs and 12 chickens ultimately. But there are questions.

```
 def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1): #we have got 12 chickens here?
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
           return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return[None, None]

def barnYard():
    heads = int(raw_input('Enter number of heads:'))
    legs = int(raw_input('Enter number of legs:'))
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs = None:
       print 'there is no solution'
    else:
        print 'number of pigs:' , pigs
        pirnt 'number of chickes:', chickens
```

I am stuck here `for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1):`. If we get the number chickens in the for loop line then we can proceed calculating the number of pigs right? but how do we get 12 chickens the line i commented above? Please consider the number of my inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1)://what is this doing?
```

is just a for loop which will loop from `0` until `numHeads + 1`. If `numHeads` is 10, it will loop from 0 until 10, if `numHeads` is 100, it will loop from 0 until 100

see the python for loop function: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

and for the range function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

e.g.

```
>>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

each time it loops, `numchick` takes the respective value, i.e. `numchick` will take all values starting from 0: 0, 1, 2, ... , numHeads

Comment: for example lets say numHeads = 10 so we get a range from 0 to 9. so is this adding 1 with every number from 0 to 9? like 0 + 1, 1 + 1 etc. something like this? or i am wrong?

Comment: numHeads=10 and it doesn't change in your code. so it will go up to 10. it is not adding any number to numHeads because it doesn't change, it is the upper limit of your for loop. the only number that changes i numChick which starts from 0 and then becomes 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, up to 10. Hope that helps. Please accept my answer as described here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes i will accept this. Please let me know where we reach after numChick becomes 10. so eventually numChick becomes 10 and adds 1 to it? so 10 + 1 = 11? is this the final thing we get there?

Comment: as you can see from the example I provided >>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] goes up until 10. So in your case if numChick is 10 it will go up until 10. Think about it this way: If range(min, max) it goes up until max-1. Please accept my answer. Cheers

Comment: hello i have shared the full codes(check out the question again) for the sake of understanding. Please can you clarify the points i mentioned ?Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you a new question. You have many mistakes. numChicks does not exist (numChick exists but not numChicks, unless you want them to be the same thing). Post a new question and send me the link to reply there !

Comment: okay. few typos and i am fixing them and giving you a link. Thanks

Comment: please go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322548/python-counting-number-of-livestock

Answer (score 1):

for x in range( y, z ) will create a loop that iterates (at max) y-z times and assigns the value produced by range() to x. Eg

```
for x in range( 0, 10 )
```

x will be 0, 1, 2, etc on the first, second, third, etc iteration

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range
range(start, stop[, step]) produces a numbered list from start to stop (inclusive) in increments of step. (Start and step may be omitted and default to 0 and 1 resp.)

```
range( 0, numHeads+1 )
```

will return the range [0,numHeads+1]
ex if numHeads is 5 then

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

is produced.

Answer (score 0):

From python manual about [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) :

```
range(stop)
range(start, stop[, step])
```

This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must be plain integers. Example:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1, 11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> range(0, 30, 5)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>>> range(0, 10, 3)
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> range(0, -10, -1)
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
>>> range(0)
[]
>>> range(1, 0)
[]
```