# Python counting number of livestock

Tags: python, python-2.7

To illustrate this we have two type of animals one is pig and other is chicken. A user inputs the number of heads and legs for this two particular type of animals. for example if we run this and input 20 heads and 56 legs we get 12 chicken and 8 pigs. Have a look at here:

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1): # how we get 12 chickens here?
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks # numpigs = 20 - 12 = 8 ?
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks # 4 * 8 + 2 * 12 ?
        if totLegs == numLegs:
           return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return[None, None]

def barnYard():
    heads = int(raw_input('Enter number of heads:'))
    legs = int(raw_input('Enter number of legs:'))
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs = None:
       print 'there is no solution'
    else:
        print 'number of pigs:' , pigs
        pirnt 'number of chickes:', chickens
```

we calculate `totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks` knowing that pigs have 4 legs and chickens have 2 and later verify if this matches with the input number of legs right? but the query is at this point `for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):` how it finds that number of chicken is 12? if number of chicken is not found we can not proceed with the next lines if i am not wrong. Can you explain this? this confuses me a lot. The algebra version can be found here. [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128234006/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57511.html)

Comment: in any case, this won't work:    `if pigs = None` (add `=`)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`Don't make your life more complicated than it already is`, simply use the `print command to see the intermediate values`, it is `simple algebra`. By the way, you have `many errors` in your code and it `doesn't even compile` (mostly `typos` such as `pirnt` instead of `print`). See here the `fixed code which works:`

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1): #we have got 12 chickens here?
        print "numChicks = ", numChicks
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        print "numPigs = ", numPigs
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks
        print "totLegs = ",totLegs
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            print "numLegs = ",numLegs
            print "numPigs = ",numPigs
            print "numChicks = ",numChicks
            return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return[None, None]

def barnYard():
    heads = int(raw_input('Enter number of heads:'))
    legs = int(raw_input('Enter number of legs:'))
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs == None:
       print 'there is no solution'
    else:
        print 'number of pigs:' , pigs
        print 'number of chicken:', chickens



if __name__ == "__main__":
    barnYard()
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter number of heads:20
Enter number of legs:56
numChicks =  0
numPigs =  20
totLegs =  80
numChicks =  1
numPigs =  19
totLegs =  78
numChicks =  2
numPigs =  18
totLegs =  76
numChicks =  3
numPigs =  17
totLegs =  74
numChicks =  4
numPigs =  16
totLegs =  72
numChicks =  5
numPigs =  15
totLegs =  70
numChicks =  6
numPigs =  14
totLegs =  68
numChicks =  7
numPigs =  13
totLegs =  66
numChicks =  8
numPigs =  12
totLegs =  64
numChicks =  9
numPigs =  11
totLegs =  62
numChicks =  10
numPigs =  10
totLegs =  60
numChicks =  11
numPigs =  9
totLegs =  58
numChicks =  12
numPigs =  8
totLegs =  56
numLegs =  56
numPigs =  8
numChicks =  12
number of pigs: 8
number of chicken: 12
```

It is simple math. `You have 20 heads, 56 legs. every pigs has 4 legs, every chicken 2 legs`

So

```
56 = 4*X+2*Y
   X+Y=20
```

Which means that `X = 20 - Y`

Then `56 = 4*(20-Y)+2*Y => 56 = 80 -4Y+2Y => 2Y = 80 - 56 => 2Y = 24 => Y = 12 Chicken`

Then `X + 12 = 20 => X = 8 Pigs`

:D

Hope it helps !!